# will the ladder reach the height of a 3.5m window.

Tags: geometry

A ladder of length 4m leans against the wall of a house. The foot of the ladder is 2m from the wall. Will the ladder reach a window 3.5m high?

Comment: **HINT**: The ladder, the floor and the wall form a right-angled triangle

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In a right triangle, knowing two sides is enough to determine the third side. For the ladder to reach the window, the third side, which represents the distance from the ground to the point of contact of the ladder with the house, must be at least the height of the window above ground.

You will use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the third side. Note that the ladder itself corresponds to the hypotenuse of the right triangle.

There are various simplifying assumptions here. Presumably one need only climb partway up the ladder if it is longer than needed, and one apparently can't reach the window even if the ladder is 1mm below it.